# Copying existing files in a s3 Bucket to another s3 bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk, boto3

I have a existing s3 bucket which contains large amount of files. I want to run a lambda function every 1 minute and copy those files to another destination s3 bucket.

My function is:

```
s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
clientname=boto3.client('s3')
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    bucket = 'test-bucket-for-transfer-check'
    try:
        response = clientname.list_objects(
            Bucket=bucket,
            MaxKeys=5
        )

        for record in response['Contents']:
            key = record['Key']
            copy_source = {
                'Bucket': bucket,
                'Key': key
            }
            try:
                destbucket = s3.Bucket('serverless-demo-s3-bucket')
                destbucket.copy(copy_source, key)
                print('{} transferred to destination bucket'.format(key))

            except Exception as e:
                print(e)
                print('Error getting object {} from bucket {}. '.format(key, bucket))
                raise e
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        raise e
```

Now how can I make sure the function is copying new files each time it runs??

Comment: Refer https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/copy-s3-buckets-lambda/ and https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/content-replication-using-aws-lambda-and-amazon-s3/

Comment: @Venkatesh Those are for the event notifications approach I think...And My scenario is different...Any other thing to try out?

Comment: What do you mean by scenario is different ? Can you explain what are you looking for exactly in the question itself ? And also please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I suggest reading the documentation and trying something first. You need to ask a specific question about a specific problem here

Comment: Can you also post the output you're getting when you run this code.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose the two buckets in question are Bucket-A and Bucket-B
and task to be done is copy files from Bucket-A --> Bucket-B

1. Lamba-1 (code in the question) reads all files from Bucket-A and copy them one-by-one to Bucket-B in a loop.
2. In the same loop it also puts one entry in DynamoDb table say
   "Copy_Logs" with column File_key and Flag. 
   Where File_Key is the object key of the file
   and Flag is set to false telling the state of copy operation
3. Now configure events on Bucket-B to invoke a Lambda-2 on every put and multi-part upload
4. Now Lambda-2 will read the object key from S3 notification payload and updates its respective record in DynamoDb table with flag set to true.

Now you have all records in DynamoDb table "Copy-Logs" which files were copied successfully and which were not.

HIH

[Update]
I missed the last part. It's a one-way sync. you can also get the list/names of files from both buckets and then do a difference of these set(file names) and upload the rest to target bucket.

Comment: I found another solution. I can use the 'Marker' parameter in list_object request to remember the last file that was listed. I initially create a environment variable named 'marker' and set its value to empty. After a successful execution of the function, I change the 'marker' value to the key name of last s3 object listed. so the next time the function executes s3 client will list objects starting from marker position.
response = clientname.list_objects(
            Bucket=bucket,
            MaxKeys=5,
            Marker=os.environ['marker']
        )

Comment: Is this a nice way to do?

Comment: I missed the last part. It's a one-way sync. you can also get the list/names of files from both buckets and then do a difference of these set(file names) and upload the rest to target bucket.